# trouble Converting function from objective-C to swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm using a framework that uses the function below, I tried converting it to swift using a website, but it was unable to do so. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
[databaseChanges enumerateDocumentChangeDetailsUsingBlock:^(METDocumentChangeDetails *documentChangeDetails, BOOL *stop) {
      ...
    }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
databaseChanges.enumerateDocumentChangeDetailsUsingBlock({
    (documentChangeDetails:METDocumentChangeDetails,
     stop:UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void in
    // ...
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the framework available in swift? If it's not you will have to create a bridging header as described here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Then you will be able to easily figure out how to call this function using Xcode's auto complete.

Just type:

```
databaseChanges.enu
```

And xcode will give you the way it should be called.

**Edit:**

I assume you are using [this library](https://github.com/martijnwalraven/meteor-ios). Which offers support for swift. So your problem is purely about how to write the block in Swift 3 syntax. 
[matt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41498062/1068522) has the solution for that.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 3:

```
databaseChanges.enumerateDocumentChangeDetails { details, stop in

}
```

It might suggest all sorts of other syntactic noise (types for `details` and `stop`, etc.), but this distills it down to the essentials, using type inference to keep the code nice and expressive.

And if you want to stop it, it's

```
stop.pointee = true
```